Div shows resize corner and cursor changes but will not resize
Here is the relevant CSS & HTML.


#itemDescription,
#itemDescription2 {
  overflow-y : scroll;
  height     : 5em;
  min-height : 5em;
  max-height : 20em;
}

#itemDescription2 {
  display : inline-block;
  resize  : vertical;
}
<div class='fieldInput fullWidth' id='itemDescription2' readonly>Some PHP content here...</div>



The DIV shows a resize corner properly but will not do anything.
Already looked at things like other CSS locking in size etc.
Can I get some hints here?

Could you describe more what 'will not do anything' means? Running your code I can drag the corner down OK.

using readonlyon a simple <div> element doesn't make any sens.

resize is working well.
But you set it to vertical. set to both

The readonly was a leftover from when the DIV used to be a text area; I changed it because I need actual HTML to be rendered inside... But wanted to retain the resizability.

The code you have included does not demonstrate the problem you describe. Please make a runnable snippet which you have tested does show the problem otherwise we cannot help other than by guessing.
